# PHP/HTML form data to send as an email from my GMAIL account

Tags: php, forms, email, gmail

I am trying to send an email to myself when someone fills in the form on my web page. My form looks like this:

```
    <form id="contactForm" action="#" method="post">
                <fieldset>                      
                    <p>
                        <label for="name" >Name</label>
                        <input name="name"  id="name" type="text" class="form-poshytip" title="Enter your full name" />
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label for="email" >Email</label>
                        <input name="email"  id="email" type="text" class="form-poshytip" title="Enter your email address" />
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label for="web">Website</label>
                        <input name="web"  id="web" type="text" class="form-poshytip" title="Enter your website" />
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label for="comments">Message</label>
                        <textarea  name="comments"  id="comments" rows="5" cols="20" class="form-poshytip" title="Enter your comments"></textarea>
                    </p>
                    <!-- send mail configuration -->
                    <input type="hidden" value=EMAIL" name="to" id="to" />
                    <input type="hidden" value="Email received from Website" name="subject" id="subject" />
                    <input type="hidden" value="send-mail.php" name="sendMailUrl" id="sendMailUrl" />
                    <!-- ENDS send mail configuration -->

                    <p><input type="button" value="Send" name="submit" id="submit" /> <span id="error" class="warning">Message</span></p>
                </fieldset>

            </form>
```

and the PHP i have looks like this:

```
<?php
//vars
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$to = explode(',', $_POST['to'] );

$from = $_POST['email'];

//data
$msg = "NAME: "  .$_POST['name']    ."<br>\n";
$msg .= "EMAIL: "  .$_POST['email']    ."<br>\n";
$msg .= "WEBSITE: "  .$_POST['web']    ."<br>\n";
$msg .= "COMMENTS: "  .$_POST['comments']    ."<br>\n";

//Headers
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
$headers .= "From: <".$from. ">" ;

$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array(
        'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'port' => '465',
        'auth' => true,
        'username' => 'EMAIL',
        'password' => 'PASSWORD'
    ));

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $msg);
?>
```

Where EMAIL and PASSWORD are replaced with the values....

Can anyone advise on what to do?

Comment: whats the problem here ?

Comment: the email never comes through

Comment: try `if($mail) echo "mail sent"; else echo "mail not sent";` this tell whether `send()` has any problems

Comment: I think that the port for Gmail is 587.

Also, why not set the SMTP details in the php.ini in the mail function, use sendmail and then 
@mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers)

Comment: I have no experience in PHP unfortunatly! just been trying to figure this out with no joy!

Comment: I thought someone with more knowledge would be able to give a solution easily as it would be a common requirement

Comment: You need to change `action="#"` to `action=""` and then `<input type="button" value="Send" name="submit" id="submit" />` to `<input type="submit" value="Send" name="submit" id="submit" />` @MarkMcK - However, if you're using two seperate files, then you will need to use something like `action="sendmail.php"` along with my other suggestion about your submit button.

Comment: And you're also missing a quote for `value=EMAIL"` and why are you doing `$to = explode(',', $_POST['to'] );`?

Comment: You can add 'debug' => true to your parameter list to have Mail::Factory dump out debug info. I agree with @Declan Greally about the port, and I would add that the host should just be 'smtp.gmail.com', (should negotiate TLS automatically).

Comment: Your parameters are off `($to, $headers, $msg)` headers goes last. Try `($to, $subject,$msg, $headers)` it's TO, then Subject, then Message, then Headers.

Answer (score 1):

Update host to smtp.gmail.com and port to 587 and update us with the results.

Answer (score 1):

### Edit (all  in one)

**PHP - and HTML together** (and replace the `mail()` function with your own SMTP)

I.e.:

```
$mail = $smtp->send($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);
```

New code:

```
<?php
//vars

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$subject = $_POST['subject'];

$to = "email@example.com";

$from = $_POST['email'];

//data
$msg = "NAME: "  .$_POST['name']    ."<br>\n";
$msg .= "EMAIL: "  .$_POST['email']    ."<br>\n";
$msg .= "WEBSITE: "  .$_POST['web']    ."<br>\n";
$msg .= "COMMENTS: "  .$_POST['comments']    ."<br>\n";

//Headers
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
$headers .= "From: <".$from. ">" ;

// insert with your SMTP

mail ($to, $subject,$msg, $headers); 
echo "sent";
}
?>


<form id="contactForm" action="" method="post">
    <fieldset>                      
        <p>
            <label for="name" >Name</label>
            <input name="name"  id="name" type="text" class="form-poshytip" title="Enter your full name" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="email" >Email</label>
            <input name="email"  id="email" type="text" class="form-poshytip" title="Enter your email address" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="web">Website</label>
            <input name="web"  id="web" type="text" class="form-poshytip" title="Enter your website" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="comments">Message</label>
            <textarea  name="comments"  id="comments" rows="5" cols="20" class="form-poshytip" title="Enter your comments"></textarea>
        </p>
        <!-- send mail configuration -->
        <input type="hidden" value="Email received from Website" name="subject" id="subject" />

        <!-- ENDS send mail configuration -->

        <p><input type="submit" value="Send" name="submit" id="submit" /> <span id="error" class="warning">Message</span></p>
    </fieldset>

</form>
```

---

### Original answer

There were quite a few issues with your code.

Your parameters are off `($to, $headers, $msg)` headers goes last and the `$subject` was not included; it must be in there.

The syntax is `($to, $subject,$msg, $headers)`

it's TO, then Subject, then Message, then Headers. As per [`the mail() manual`](http://php.net/mail) Even though you are using SMTP, ***mail is mail.***

And I don't know why you're doing:

```
<input type="hidden" value="send-mail.php" name="sendMailUrl" id="sendMailUrl" />
```

Just set it in your form's `action=`

Here is what worked for me: and you can replace:

```
mail ($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);
```

with (and if it works for you) It seems there were other answers given in regards to this.

```
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array(
        'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'port' => '465',
        'auth' => true,
        'username' => 'EMAIL',
        'password' => 'PASSWORD'
    ));

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $msg);
```

**PHP - tested** (send-mail.php)

```
<?php
//vars

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$subject = $_POST['subject'];

$to = "email@example.com";

$from = $_POST['email'];

//data
$msg = "NAME: "  .$_POST['name']    ."<br>\n";
$msg .= "EMAIL: "  .$_POST['email']    ."<br>\n";
$msg .= "WEBSITE: "  .$_POST['web']    ."<br>\n";
$msg .= "COMMENTS: "  .$_POST['comments']    ."<br>\n";

//Headers
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
$headers .= "From: <".$from. ">" ;

mail ($to, $subject,$msg, $headers);
echo "sent";
}
?>
```

**HTML form**

```
<form id="contactForm" action="send-mail.php" method="post">
    <fieldset>                      
        <p>
            <label for="name" >Name</label>
            <input name="name"  id="name" type="text" class="form-poshytip" title="Enter your full name" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="email" >Email</label>
            <input name="email"  id="email" type="text" class="form-poshytip" title="Enter your email address" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="web">Website</label>
            <input name="web"  id="web" type="text" class="form-poshytip" title="Enter your website" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="comments">Message</label>
            <textarea  name="comments"  id="comments" rows="5" cols="20" class="form-poshytip" title="Enter your comments"></textarea>
        </p>
        <!-- send mail configuration -->
        <input type="hidden" value="Email received from Website" name="subject" id="subject" />

        <!-- ENDS send mail configuration -->

        <p><input type="submit" value="Send" name="submit" id="submit" /> <span id="error" class="warning">Message</span></p>
    </fieldset>

</form>
```

---

**Footnotes:**

Missing quote in `value=EMAIL"` but that has been replaced in my PHP with:

```
$to = "email@example.com";
```

Comment: i removed my form and replaced with your code. now when i hit the submit button the code opens like a new page, this is getting to me I am a Java/Web developer and thought this would be easy, its just i dont know the syntax

Comment: The code I posted should basically be "out of the box". Both my HTML and PHP should be used. If you used only 1/2 of it and are still using the same form, then it will do just that. I pre-tested this before posting. @MarkMcK

Comment: I will post an Edit to have everything inside the same page. That way, it should work as is. You will need to replace some of the functions with your own SMTP. @MarkMcK - Give me a a minute or so ;-)

Comment: You're welcome. Ok, reload to see my **Edit** @MarkMcK

Comment: I'm question the `send()` function though. That's a function that doesn't seem to be called. How are you using it? @MarkMcK

Comment: So, how are you making out, any progress? @MarkMcK

Comment: No :( i have set up an account with MailJet to send my emails using thier SMTP settings but still cant get it

Comment: they have provided this:

Comment: <?php
 
require_once "Mail.php";
 
$headers = array ('From' => 'You <your_sender@address.com>',
       'Subject' => 'My first email by Mailjet');
 
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
           array ('host' => 'ssl://in.mailjet.com',
                   'port' => 465,
                    'auth' => true,
                    'username' => 'your_Mailjet_API_Key',
                    'password' => 'your_Mailjet_Secret_Key'));
 
$mail = $smtp->send('Somebody <recipient@example.com>', $headers, 'Hello from Mailjet & PEAR !');
 
?>

Comment: And you can't use PHP's `mail()` function; have you tried it? And what is inside `Mail.php`? @MarkMcK

Comment: i havent got a Mail.php yet, i only just signed up... im going to go onto W3C schools and do a PHP lesson... ill get back to you when i get it working.... thanks so much for your help

Comment: You're welcome Mark. I filled out the form with an example Email address just now. Let me know if you receive it. Also, check your Spam box. @MarkMcK - However, am pretty sure you have access to using PHP's mail function which you can use as I shown on my code. You just need to replace the Email with yours and not in your HTML form.

Comment: you sent it to my email? nothing has came through

Comment: No, I only filled the form and pressed "send". Another thing I noticed is that your file (contact form) ends with `.html` since you're using PHP, it needs to be `.php` for my code to work. @MarkMcK

Answer (score 0):

Here's a cheap and easy way to do it.

In your php.ini replace the relevant parts of the mail function with

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port = 587

; For Win32 only.
sendmail_from = EMAILADDRESSHERE
```

Replace sendmail.ini with

```
[sendmail] 
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com

smtp_port=587

error_logfile=error.log

auth_username=EMAILADDRESSHERE
auth_password=PASSWORDHERE

force_sender=EMAILADDRESSHERE
```

Then in your code, send an email much the same except write it as

```
 mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers)
```

or modify to suit.

Comment: `@mail` the `@` should not be used.

Comment: Oh dear, you're right. Just pasted that last function from a file I'm testing, forgot that I'd suppressed the warnings.

Comment: And in some cases, it even prevents mail from being sent.

Comment: Curiosity: Under what circumstances does suppression cause mail() to not send?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check first the value of variable $to is a correct mail direction. Based on the code you posted probably will wrong.

On the php code you call the class Mail but you don't include/require, add this:

```
// Pear Mail Library
require_once "Mail.php";
```

After send mail you cant show the result with this:

```
if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
    echo('<p>' . $mail->getMessage() . '</p>');
} else {
    echo('<p>Message successfully sent!</p>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, check your spam in your mailbox. If gmail has received your mail, it must be there. If not, check your mail server configuration and if it is authorized to send mail for your domain. You can also check mail server logs for potential problems.

In any case, I would recommend you to use solutions like [Mailjet](http://www.mailjet.com/) or [MailChimp](http://mailchimp.com). You can sign up for basic package and get your email. The advantage with the solution like this is that you dont need to be maintaining your mail server and you can check the status of every mail being processed.